# Solspace Calendar: How to move existing entries to calendar channel?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

So I recently bought the Solspace Calendar Add-On, because my site (that is already running) needed better functionality for the event dates. Problem is that I can't use the calendar field type on the existing channel... I have hundreds of entries in that channel and now I'm wondering how I can easily move those entries to the calendar channel. How would I go and do that?

Thanks in advance,

Marijn

Answer (score 1):

Importing into Solspace Calendar can be done putting a URL pointing to an .ics file in the **URL to iCalendar (.ics) file** custom field in the **Calendar: Calendars** channel.

What you could do is create an .ics file output in a regular EE template using {exp:channel:entries}. Then save this output as an .ics file and use it to import into Calendar as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do what I want. Basically I want the Calendar: Events channel to be an exact copy of the events channel I already have (with all custom fields and with all entries copied) except for the new calendar custom field. I'm guessing the ics file won't take the custom fields into account..

Best thing would be if a regular channel could use the calendar custom field. But that's not an option right?

Thanks

Comment: So ignore the Calendar custom field (and therefore event data) then? If so, you might have to enter your event data manually in the Calendar custom field later. If you simply want to move the custom field data from your original channel into the "Calendar: Events" channel, you could use [Solspace Importer](http://www.solspace.com/docs/Importer). You'll need to create a CSV, XML or JSON output of your original channel data for Importer to read and import into "Calendar: Events". You could try doing this *after* importing event data with your .ics file (you can update entries with Importer).

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the existing channel mimic the Calendar Event channel? It's so strange that you have a Calendar custom field, but you can't use it on any other channel.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. You **must** use the channels and custom field groups created by Calendar for Calendar to function correctly.

Comment: I noticed that if I change the event_weblog id in the calendar preferences row in the database to the id of my own channel, that I can use the Calendar custom field on that channel.. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but I guess it could work. I think it would be a great feature if you could choose one of the existing channels as the events channel upon installing.

Comment: Is this still the situation - I can't assign a Calendar fieldtype to a pre-existing Events channel??